# Stop Google automatically to copy favorites from one computer to another

Tags: google-chrome

I have some favorite sites added to favorites in google Chrome.

Now with my surprise I saw that these links  also show up in my work computer!!!

No clue how they came here!!!

I think Google somehow transferred them( I logged to my gmail in theoffice).
This is not good as I do not want my office mates to see my personal links

Question: is this a known issue and if yes how to prevent it.

Comment: It's a feature you enabled: "When you're signed in to Chrome on different devices, you can choose what information will sync across them -- such as your apps, bookmarks, history, and extensions." https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome stores lots of information on the cloud, so that you can acces it on multiple devices. I personally like this behaviour, but I understand you're unsettled by Chrome doing it in the background.

To stop it you have to adjust sync settings. Go to **Settings**, then click **Advanced sync settings**, choose option **Choose what to sync** and untick anything you would not like to be synced between machines.

I've not tested it, so I don't know if this is device setting, or global setting.

Comment: This is a per-machine setting. After altering the settings as described above, bookmark changes on that machine won't be reflected on others and vice versa.