# The full web browsing history of my home computer has fully got synced into my office computer web browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I use Google chrome at my office and at my home. Today I discovered that all the websites I did brows yesterday at home, all of the histories are present at my office computer's Google chrome browser. Even in the history page in Google chrome my Home-pc's name is also present. I searched how to remove it but I didn't find any answer. I closed Google chrome browser and then tried uninstalling it from my office computer then also it is not getting uninstalled. Its displaying a message that "Close all the tabs in Google chrome then try."

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you login to Google Chrome using the same account on two computers, they will sync. If you do not want your work chrome to be synced to your home chrome, sign out (Head and shoulders icon next to minimize) of your work chrome and create a new account (Or don't login at all) at work.

If you want to uninstall chrome entirely, use task manager (Ctrl-Shift-Esc) to close all chrome.exe processes, if you still cannot uninstall it's probably some extension giving you grief, uninstall them all first (chrome://extensions) and then try again.

Comment: I feel like you're blowing up a pound because a puppy peed on your rug. You could simply disable bookmark sync, details [here](http://superuser.com/a/908632/194694).

Comment: From the user's question, it seems like they didn't want any syncing to occur between their home and work computers, creating a seperate account for their work login (Incase their desk changes etc) seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant history sync.

Comment: To my all friends, I have different a\c. At office I use my corporate email id and at home I use my personal gmail Id. I rarely open my personal gmail Id at my offcie and I rarely open my office Id at home. And in advance sync settings all options are unselected from the beggining here in my office chrome.

Comment: Another thing. In settings on People option my home Pc name is coming by default. I am removing It but still it is coming by default again.

Comment: @Jack: I do not have required reputation else I would have share you the screenshot. What can be the problem?

Comment: The chrome sign in is seperate from gmail etc. The button for chrome sign in is next to minimize, if you click there, is that account the same one you are signed into at home? (On chrome, not gmail/google)

Comment: @Jack, Yes I just logged out myself from chrome. Its done from here in my office computer. Need to check it from my home computer. Thanks. Hope this was the cause for the trouble.